# Receiving warning in file.rename in R. How to resolve it?

Tags: r, rename, file-rename, r-raster

I have various files with following nomenclature:

```
c_gls_ALDH-AL-DH-BB_200602030000_CUSTOM_VGT_V1.4.1
c_gls_ALDH-AL-DH-BB_200602130000_CUSTOM_VGT_V1.4.1
c_gls_ALDH-AL-DH-BB_200602210000_CUSTOM_VGT_V1.4.1
c_gls_ALDH-AL-DH-BB_200603030000_CUSTOM_VGT_V1.4.1
```

The numeric in middle of file name represents year, month, date. I want to rename all the files at once while keeping only the dates i.e., '20060203' for each file and want to remove 'c_gls_ALDH-AL-DH-BB_' and '0000_CUSTOM_VGT_V1.4.1' from the file names.

I am using following code in R:

```
fromfile <- c(list.files("F:/Albedo_USCRN/Data/Goodwell_Dir/Out/BB/"))
tofile <- sub(".*_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1.tiff", fromfile)
tofile <- sub(".*_(\\d+)0000_.*", "\\1.tiff", fromfile)
file.rename(fromfile, tofile)
```

When I type tofile, I can see file names have changed as desired but when I type file.rename, as output, I am receiving FALSE FALSE...and it gives me a warning that "In file.rename(fromfile, tofile) :  cannot rename file 'c_gls_ALDH-AL-DH-BB_200602030000_CUSTOM_VGT_V1.4.1.tiff' to '20060203.tiff', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Why is it showing this? How can I resolve it?

Comment: I assume you need to prepend the path to the file names.

Comment: @Roland where in file.rename? Could you please explain how should I do it?

Comment: You just `paste` the path in front of the file names. I don't know what else I'm supposed to explain here.

Comment: @Michael_Brun Try setting your working directory to the folder where the files are stored first? i.e. `setwd("F:/Albedo_USCRN/Data/Goodwell_Dir/Out/BB/")` before your first line of code.